# how can I make the "updated" of mongodb stop when updating a field of a nested array?

Tags: mongodb

I have a database like this:

```
  {
        "universe":"comics",
        "saga":[
           {
              "name":"x-men",
              "characters":[
                 {
                    "character":"wolverine",
                    "picture":"618035022351.png"
                 },
                 {
                    "character":"wolverine",
                    "picture":"618035022352.png"
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "universe":"dc",
        "saga":[
           {
              "name":"spiderman",
              "characters":[
                 {
                    "character":"venom",
                    "picture":"618035022353.png"
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
     }
```

And with this code, I update the field where `name: wolverine`:

```
db.getCollection('collection').findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    "universe": "comics"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "saga.$[outer].characters.$[inner].character": "lobezno",
      "saga.$[outer].characters.$[inner].picture": "618035022354.png"
    }
  },
  /*{
    "saga.characters": 1
  },*/
  {
    "arrayFilters": [
      {
        "outer.name": "x-men"
      },
      {
        "inner.character": "wolverine"
      }
    ],
      "multi":false
  }

)
```

I want to just update the first object where there is a match, and stop it.

For example, if I have an array of 100,000 elements and the object where the match is, is in the tenth position, he will update that record, but he will continue going through the entire array and this seems ineffective to me even though he already did the update.

Note: if I did the update using an `_id` inside of `universe.saga.characters` instead of doing the update using the `name`, it would still loop through the rest of the elements.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

#### Update using `arrayFilters` conditions

I don't think it will find and update through loop, and It does not matter if collection have 100,000 sub documents, because here is nice explanation in [$[<identifier>]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_%5B%3Cidentifier%3E%5D) and has mentioned:

- *The `$[<identifier>]` to define an identifier to update only those array elements that match the corresponding filter document in the `arrayFilters`*
- *In the update document, use the `$[<identifier>]` filtered positional operator to define an identifier, which you then reference in the array filter documents. But make sure you cannot have an array filter document for an identifier if the identifier is not included in the update document.*

#### Update using `_id`

Your point,

> *Note: if I did the update using an `_id` inside of `universe.saga.characters` instead of doing the update using the name, it would still loop through the rest of the elements.*

MongoDB will certainly use the `_id` index. Here is the nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42003815/8987128) on question [MongoDB Update Query Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000950/mongo-db-update-query-performance), from this you will get an better idea on above point

#### Update using indexed fields

You can create index according to your query section of update command, Here [MongoDB Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) and [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/) has explained why index is important,

In your example, lets see with examples:

> **Example 1:** If document have 2 sub documents and when you update and check with [explain("executionStats")](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html), assume it will take 1 second to update,
>
> quick use [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MV24OzyEeG9) *(this platform will not support update query)*

> **Example 2:** If document have 1000 sub documents and when you update and check with [explain("executionStats")](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html), might be it will take more then 1 second,
>
> If provide index on fields (`universe`, `saga.characters.character` and `saga.characters.picture`) then definitely it will take less time then usual without index, main benefit of index it will direct point to indexed fields.
>
> quick use [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vK99sJmbrjb) *(this platform will not support update query)*

#### Create Index for your fields

```
db.maxData.createIndex({ 
    "universe": 1, 
    "saga.characters.character": 1, 
    "saga.characters.picture": 1
})
```

> For more experiment use above 2 examples data with index and without index and check `executionStats` you will get more clarity.

Comment: wow, you're a crack, it's a lot of valuable information. excuse my ignorance, but to be more clear I summarize this question:

1- even if you do an updated in a nested array using `_id`, will the rest of the elements follow the loop, even if it has found the match? or it will stop the moment it finds the match.

Comment: I really don't know internal mechanism of update, how it will search for update, But definitely they would have think on this kind of problem, my thinking is yes on *"even if you do an updated in a nested array using _id, will the rest of the elements follow the loop"* because why they have provided `updateOne` function? might be it will stop searching when first will find and update.

Comment: it seems incredible that there is no documentation of something like this ..

Comment: keep searching and if you find anything please update, might be i am wrong or added information is incomplete or not able to search relevant information.